# How to solve "plugin failed code 127" compiling with nanopb

Tags: python-3.x, protobuf-c, nanopb

I am trying to compile a c++ code in an conan enviroment, here are details:

- Ubuntu 18.04 WSL x86-64
- Windowns 10 x64
- python 3.7.5
- protoc 3.19.4
- The project is located at /mnt/c/project
- The build directory is located at /mnt/c/build

The build occurs without any errors but when I try to compile with "ninja" it throws an error related to protoc-gen-nanopb, as you can see attached image.

I tried to install a new protobuf from its c++ source, i added the LD_LIBRARY_PATH that was missing, and I have also tried to clean everything and erase all the files and build again. Everything seems to fail. I believe it's related to compatibility between protobuf and my python version, but I am not sure.

Could someone help me understand how to solve it? I am new to ubuntu and stackoverflow and i am sorry if some information is missing. In this case, just ask.

[Error 127](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beXsl.png)

Comment: You could try running `protoc-gen-nanopb` directly to see if it gives a better error message. The error messages should go to `protoc` output also, but perhaps your build system is hiding them for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After a entire day trying to solve it, I reinstalled the entire environment and it worked. I seems that it was a compatibility issue.